# Is it possible to simplify this code with collection polymorphism?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have to different collections Characters, and Souls, that share a lot of the same attributes and used within the same context. This means that every time I want to read/write to these collections, Ill have to do a "type check", and then duplicate the code twice as seen below. Is there a way to accomplish

```
Polymorphic.update()..
```

instead of

```
(Pseudocode)
if target.is(Character)
  same logic..
  Character.update(same query/fields)..
else
  same logic..
  Soul.update(same query/fields)..
```

Complete code below

```
  #
  # Adds a new condition instance to target
  #
  addCondition: (effect, target) ->

    name        = effect.name
    maxDuration = effect.maxDuration
    curDuration = if effect.curDuration then effect.curDuration else maxDuration
    maxStack    = effect.maxStack
    curStack    = if effect.curStack then effect.curStack else 1
    stackable   = if maxStack then true else false

    if target.location  <--- This is my type check, only the Character collection has a location field

      character = Characters.findOne({_id: target._id, 'conditions.name': name}, { fields: {'conditions.$': 1} })
      if character then existingCondition = character.conditions[0]

      if existingCondition and stackable

        # Apply additional stack and refresh duration
        if existingCondition.curStack < existingCondition.maxStack
          Characters.update({ _id: target._id, 'conditions.name': name }, { $inc: { 'conditions.$.curStack': 1 }, $set: { 'conditions.$.curDuration': maxDuration } })

        else
          Characters.update({ _id: target._id, 'conditions.name': name }, { $set: { 'conditions.$.curDuration': maxDuration } })

      else if existingCondition and !stackable
        Characters.update({ _id: target._id, 'conditions.name': name }, { $set: { 'conditions.$.curDuration': maxDuration } })

      else
        effect = _.extend(effect, {curDuration: curDuration, curStack: curStack})
        Characters.update(_id: target._id, {$addToSet: { conditions: effect }})

    else
      soul = Souls.findOne({_id: target._id, 'conditions.name': name}, { fields: {'conditions.$': 1} })
      if soul then existingCondition = soul.conditions[0]

      if existingCondition and stackable

        # Apply additional stack and refresh duration
        if existingCondition.curStack < existingCondition.maxStack
          Souls.update({ _id: target._id, 'conditions.name': name }, { $inc: { 'conditions.$.curStack': 1 }, $set: { 'conditions.$.curDuration': maxDuration } })

        else
          Souls.update({ _id: target._id, 'conditions.name': name }, { $set: { 'conditions.$.curDuration': maxDuration } })

      else if existingCondition and !stackable
        Souls.update({ _id: target._id, 'conditions.name': name }, { $set: { 'conditions.$.curDuration': maxDuration } })

      else
        effect = _.extend(effect, {curDuration: curDuration, curStack: curStack})
        Souls.update(_id: target._id, {$addToSet: { conditions: effect }})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `type` (/`class`/`collection`) field to your doc:

```
Character.prototype.type = ->
  Character

Soul.prototype.type = ->
  Soul

...
target.type.update ...
```

Comment: somehow the prototype object is not available and it throws TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of undefined

Comment: How do you define Character?

Comment: @Characters = new Meteor.Collection('characters')

Comment: In your pseudocode, you've got `target.is(Character)`, so I assumed you also defined a singular `Character`. If you did not, it's a good idea to do so, by defining `Character = function(doc) {_.extend(this, doc);};` and transforming your collection: `Characters = new Mongo.Collection('characters', {transform: function(doc) { return new Character(doc); }});`